# Not getting data to gridview from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im not getting anything while databinding to the gridview. Can anyone help?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1000px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" `CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cars.carid,  cars.make, cars.model, cars.condition, cars.amount, img.img FROM cars INNER JOIN img ON cars.carid = img.imgid where model = '" + mod + "' and make = '" + mak + "' and variant = '" + var + "' and color = '" + col + "' and condition = '" + cond + "'",con);
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sda1.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: is there an error? do you see data in the dt?

Comment: No error.. blank page shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` otherwise you need to define columns and bindings.

Read more details on MSDN documentation [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: change your sql as "SELECT cars.carid,  cars.make, cars.model, cars.condition, cars.amount, img.img FROM cars INNER JOIN img ON cars.carid = img.imgid"  run and check the output

Comment: Something wrong with your sql statement, first try it with some parameter values in sql management studio and correct the sql statement errors. note that you haven't specify with table each column in where conditions included, that may be the issue

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much :)